# 1 character of junk warning - biber

Tags: biber

this is my first question in this forum, I dont have enough reputation the add a comment under the already existing (same) topics.
in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
```

In my .bib-file I created the following citation:

```
@article{Parente.2020,
 author = {Parente, Matteo and {van Helvert}, Max and Hamans, Ruben F. and Verbroekken, Ruth and Sinha, Rochan and Bieberle-Hütter, Anja and Baldi, Andrea},
 year = {2020},
 title = {Simple and Fast High-Yield Synthesis of Silver Nanowires},
 pages = {5759--5764},
 volume = {20},
 number = {8},
 journal = {Nano letters},
 doi = {10.1021/acs.nanolett.0c01565},
}
```

After compiling: BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/biber_tmp_v7SM/be7ebbb921cb80f8de94ccef0371dc06_14.utf8, line 419, warning: 1 characters of junk seen at toplevel
Line 419 is the top line. I already check the code and found no "zero width ..." etc. like mentioned in other topics. All other papers or articles I've added are ok. Can someone help me to find the mistake? I know its not a big mistake to just ignore the warning, but it seems better when my document has not any warnins after compiling.

Comment: the line number refers to the bib-file. You have some text outside entries. The warning is harmless, you can avoid it by using % in the bib file too.

Comment: Where are these  "text outside entries" ? How can I change the .bib-file to turn the warning off?

Comment: somewhere between a `}` that ends an entry and the `@xxx` that starts the next you have some character, perhaps a stray `,` that is being ignored. It is better and simpler to delete the character than configure biber not to warn about it. What's on the line above the fragment you showed?

Comment: I'm completely dumb as hell. There were two } above the fragment. Deleted one of the two and the problem is gone. Thanks for the support... sorry for not checking it at all